# multidimensional array in view in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array, codeigniter-3

I have the following array from my model, here the var_dump:

```
array(4) {
[0]=>
 array(1) {
   [0]=>
   array(5) {
 ["payment_student"]=>
 string(4) "2406"
 ["fee_month"]=>
 string(10) "2018-02-00"
 ["arrears"]=>
 string(1) "0"
 ["payment_description"]=>
 string(17) "Transport, 120 , "
 ["payment_amount"]=>
 string(3) "120"
   }
 }
 [1]=>
 array(1) {
   [0]=>
   array(5) {
     ["payment_student"]=>
 string(4) "2415"
 ["fee_month"]=>
 string(10) "2018-02-00"
 ["arrears"]=>
 string(1) "0"
 ["payment_description"]=>
 string(33) "Transport, 1500 , Tuition, 620 , "
 ["payment_amount"]=>
 string(4) "2120"
   }
     }
 [2]=>
     array(1) {
   [0]=>
   array(5) {
     ["payment_student"]=>
 string(4) "2175"
 ["fee_month"]=>
 string(10) "2018-02-00"
 ["arrears"]=>
 string(1) "0"
 ["payment_description"]=>
 string(17) "Transport, 620 , "
 ["payment_amount"]=>
 string(3) "620"
   }
 }
 [3]=>
 array(1) {
   [0]=>
   array(5) {
 ["payment_student"]=>
 string(4) "2087"
 ["fee_month"]=>
 string(10) "2018-02-00"
 ["arrears"]=>
 string(1) "0"
 ["payment_description"]=>
 string(33) "Transport, 1500 , Tuition, 420 , "
 ["payment_amount"]=>
 string(4) "1920"
   }
 }
}
```

here my view for loop:

```
$i=0;
foreach ($payments_view as $key => $data) { 

            ?>
                <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data[$i]['payment_student']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data[$i]['arrears']?></td>

                <td><?php echo $data[$i]['payment_description']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $data[$i]['payment_amount']+$data[$i]['arrears']; ?></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
                $i++;
 }
```

It display the 1st row, but for next rows give following error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>   Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined offset: 1
>   Filename: views/fee_register_list.php
>   Line Number: 95
>   Backtrace:
>   File: C:\xampp\htdocs\learn_ci\ksi_gentelella\application\views\fee_register_list.php
>   Line: 95
>   Function: _error_handler
>   File: C:\xampp\htdocs\learn_ci\ksi_gentelella\application\controllers\Fee_Controller.php
>   Line: 173
>   Function: view
>   File: C:\xampp\htdocs\learn_ci\ksi_gentelella\index.php
>   Line: 315
>   Function: require_once

How can I make my array simple one array so, can be able to use it. in such a shape I think its very complex.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++){
   <tr>
   $firstObj=$data[i][0];
    for($j=0;$j<5;$j++){
       <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $firstObj[$j]['payment_student']?></td>
       <td><?php echo $firstObj[$j]['arrears']?></td>
       <td><?php echo $firstObj[$j]['payment_description']; ?></td>
       <td><?php echo $firstObj[$j]['payment_amount']." ".$firstObj[$j]['arrears']; ?></td>
    }
   </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to "flatten" your array:

```
<?php foreach (array_column($payments_view, 0) as $i => $data) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $i; ?></td>
        <td><?= $data['payment_student']?></td>
        <td><?= $data['arrears']?></td>
        <td><?= $data['payment_description']; ?></td>
        <td><?= $data['payment_amount'] + $data['arrears']; ?></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Although it should not be done in view. Try to refactor your code, so your view would have data in proper format.

Comment: this give only data for index 0.

Comment: Is there any way to make this 1 simple array?

Comment: @Muhammad, this function call `array_column($payments_view, 0)` transforms your array from array-of-arrays-with-only-one-item-in-each to simple array of items.